# R: Regular expression is invalid in this locale

Tags: regex, r, unicode, locale

I have the following regular expression in an R script:

```
grepl("\xe9", "MY TEXT", fixed = FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in grepl("\xe9", "MY TEXT", fixed = FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE,  : 
regular expression is invalid in this locale
```

"\xe9" is unicode representation of "é" and is read as-is from a file.

How can I fix this? Additionally, is there a useful resource on locales w.r.t regular expression in R?

Comment: When in doubt, try escaping the \ with another \.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why @joran didn't just post this as an answer:

```
grepl("\\xe9", c("MY TEXT", "é"), fixed = FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Oh, right, @DWin, just steal joran's karma.  Oops, this isn't slashdot.  :-)